# How to use the `shard_func` in tensorflow's `tf.data.Dataset.save`

Tags: tensorflow, dataloader

### Background:

I'm working with a large dataset saved in a non-standard format.  I can write a pure python data-reader, but when called from DL dataloaders, like `tf.data.Dataset`,  it takes forever to stream over the data once.

Tensorflow's [`tf.data.Dataset.save`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#save) is a life saver.  This runs through the dataset once using the slow pure-python data loader,  and resaves it into a much faster format, and a faster dataloader can be created using the associated `load` method.  Great.

### Question

I want to save the large dataset to multiple shards.  The `save` method mentioned above allows for this with the `shard_func` argument, but [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#save) only provides an example for a single shard.   In theory multiple shards can be created based on elements of the datasets, but I don't see an obvious way to do this.

The output of `shard_func` must be a `np.int64`, but the inputs to `shard_func` are symbolic tensors that cannot be transformed to `numpy` arrays during execution.   So how is it possible to output anything other than a single `np.int64` in a deterministic way based on dataset elements?

Heres a simple example.   I want to save the dataset `[0,...,99]` into 10 shards.  Here's an attempt that fails:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(100)

def custom_shard_function(x):
    """
    Transforms x into a np.int64 between 0,..,9
    """
    return np.int64(x) % 10

dataset.save('/tmp/saved_dataset',shard_func=custom_shard_function)
```

with the error

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic tf.Tensor (args_0:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported.
```

I understand this isn't possible, but I also have no idea how to get a dynamic `np.int64` out of a symbolic tensor in a deterministic way.

I'm using TF 2.12.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I was able to get it working with this somewhat absurd solution..

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(100)

def custom_shard_function(x):
    """
    Transforms integer x into a np.int64 between 0,..,9
    """
    #return np.int64(x.numpy()) % 10
    if x % 10 == 0:
        return np.int64(0)
    elif x % 10 == 1:
        return np.int64(1)
    elif x % 10 == 2:
        return np.int64(2)
    elif x % 10 == 3:
        return np.int64(3)
    elif x % 10 == 4:
        return np.int64(4)
    elif x % 10 == 5:
        return np.int64(5)
    elif x % 10 == 6:
        return np.int64(6)
    elif x % 10 == 7:
        return np.int64(7)
    elif x % 10 == 8:
        return np.int64(8)
    elif x % 10 == 9:
        return np.int64(9)
    else:
        return np.int64(0)

dataset.save('/tmp/saved_dataset',shard_func=custom_shard_function)
```